# Convert a Problem-based model to a Solver-based model using prob2struct in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm trying to convert a problem-based model to a solver-based model so that I can use other solvers to solve my problem. The `prob2struct` function returns a structure which defines the model with some matrixes like `Aeq` and `beq`. I'm confused about what does matrix `C` and `d` in the returned structure mean. A demo code is attached below.

```
clc
clear

qprob = optimproblem;
var_x = optimvar('var_x',2);

constr = var_x >= 5;
qprob.Constraints.x_range = constr;
qprob.Constraints.xs = var_x(1) >= var_x(2) + 10;
qprob.Objective = sum((var_x - [2,3]').^2)+8;

opts = optimoptions('lsqlin','Algorithm','interior-point');
[sol,fval,exitflag,output,lambda] = solve(qprob,'options',opts);

problem = prob2struct(qprob);
```

Answer (score 0):

C and d are parameters in the linear system C*x = d.

See doc for 'lsqlin' solver https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqlin.html